# Problems with running Qt on CentOS 7

Tags: linux, qt, pyqt, centos, qt5

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication

app = QGuiApplication([])
```

When starting, it gives an error

```
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
Could not connect to any X display.
```

Tell me how to fix this? I could not find it.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the `DISPLAY` environment variable is not set. Are you running this from a graphical session? If you are running this over SSH you need to use X11 forwarding.

Assuming it is enabled on the server, you need to run ssh with the `-X` option.

You can find more information about this on [ssh man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh).

Comment: Remote connection via ssh. I do not need a GUI. I just want to process images using Qt.

Comment: Ah, then do not use QGuiApplication, use QCoreApplication

Comment: It seems that this is not a solution. For example, if I write: `fontDatabase = QFontDatabase()`, it gives an error "QFontDatabase: Must construct a QGuiApplication before accessing QFontDatabase" (I wanted to add a font from the file). In addition, the "segmentation fault" error falls on `QPainter.drawText`. I suspect that, too, because of this.

Comment: Indeed. I just tried it, you can use `QPainter` with a `QCoreApplication`, but any call to `QPainter.drawText` segfaults unless you have a `QGuiApplication`. Not sure there is a way to workaround this :(